# Running a Python File from Command Prompt that uses Pandas and one other library

Tags: python, windows, command-line, scripting, operating-system

I am trying to run a function inside a python file from command prompt. The file needs to import two python libraries, Pandas and fillpdf. All i'm trying to do is take the contents of a CSV file into a pdf file. When i try to run the function from the command prompt i get the error No module named "fillpdf".

I am not familiar with running python code from command prompt. My problem is the code i'm trying to run has two packages, pandas and fillpdf. I am getting a No module named "fillpdf" error. After googling i thought you maybe have to make a virtual environment for the given packages, can someone explain this

I have tried running the file but get "No module named 'fillpdf'"

Comment: What is your function? can you show us some code? are you using a virtual environment? have you installed `fillpdf`?

Comment: Run: python -m pip install fillpdf pandas -U  
which installs these
https://pypi.org/project/pandas/
https://pypi.org/project/fillpdf/

Then run your script:

    python <scriptName>.py